# How can I set multiple variables to their respective values?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables

My sql statement returns an array of 2 associative keys, up and down.

```
query = 'SELECT `up`,`down` FROM `records` WHERE `id`=id'
```

is there a way i can, in one line, set both variables such as:

```
$up, $down = 'SELECT `up`,`down` FROM `records` WHERE `id`=id'
```

so that up and down will take the respective values?

Comment: Why don't you share actual code here? A string is not an array.

Comment: if i knew the real code i would answer my own question

Comment: Then, start with reading through [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) and/or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If after making your SQL call, you get an associative array like this:

```
array(
  'up' => 'foo',
  'down' => 'bar'
);
```

Then you can use [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) to get the variables `$up` and `$down`.

So you could do this:

```
// no need to initialize $up and $down

extract(exec_query()); // asusming exec_query() returns the assoc array defined above
echo $up;  // will print 'foo'
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $down;  // will print 'bar'
```

*PS - While this could be done, it's really bad from a readability point of view, and I would strongly recommend against it.*

Comment: +1 for learning something new today

Answer (score 3):

The return value from `mysqli::query()` is not immediately an associative array, but a 'result set'.  And if the query fails you will not even get that, but `FALSE`.  So while you could do

```
list($up, $down) = $db->query ("SELECT up, down FROM records WHERE id='id';")->fetch_all();
```

this doesn't let you check that the query actually worked, so you're better to split it out.

Answer (score 1):

`list()` allows you to assign multiple values from one function call, however, in your case you also need to execute your query and fetch data from your database server.

For example:

```
list($up, $down) = mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```